# Ruby tempfile anomalous behavior

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file, temporary-files, pry

This is my pry session output:

```
[1] pry(SomeTask)> epub
=> #<File:/somepath/tmp/x.epub>
[2] pry(SomeTask)> epub.size
=> 134
[3] pry(SomeTask)> File.size("/somepath/tmp/x.epub")
=> 44299
[4] pry(SomeTask)> epub.class
=> Tempfile
```

I see that `File.size` yields a different result than the `size` method of the Tempfile instance.

How is this possible?

Comment: Have you changed the content of `epub` without saving the file?

Comment: What versions of Ruby and Pry are you using?

Comment: @SimoneCarletti: Seems to me thats the case. But I cannot figure out where exactly. So, I just did epub.close and epub.open and now I have files in sync. Thanks everyone for answers!

Answer (score 5):

The devil is in the details. From the docs for [`Tempfile#size`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.1/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/Tempfile.html#method-i-size) (emphasis mine):

> **size()**
>
> Returns the size of the temporary file. *As a side effect, the IO buffer is flushed before determining the size*.

What's happening is that you're using `File.size` to read the size of the file before the buffer has been flushed—i.e. before all of the bytes have been written to the file—and then you're using `Tempfile#size`, which flushes that buffer before it calculates the size:

```
tmp = Tempfile.new('foo')
tmp.write('a' * 1000)
File.size(tmp)
# => 0
tmp.size
# => 1000
```

But see what happens when you call `tmp.size` *before* `File.size(tmp)`:

```
tmp = Tempfile.new('bar')
tmp.write('a' * 1000)
tmp.size
# => 1000
File.size(tmp)
# => 1000
```

You can get the behavior you want out of `File.size` by manually flushing the buffer:

```
tmp = Tempfile.new('baz')
tmp.write('a' * 1000)
tmp.flush
File.size(tmp)
# => 1000
```

Comment: Is it ? I thought the wording are different... but they are same.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Pry version 0.10.1 on Ruby 2.2.2 and can't duplicate that situation:

```
[1] (pry) main: 0> foo = Tempfile.new('foo')
#<File:/var/folders/yb/whn8dwns6rl92jswry5cz87dsgk2n1/T/foo20150819-83612-1tpkqm4>
[2] (pry) main: 0> File.size(foo.path)
=> 0
[3] (pry) main: 0> foo.size
=> 0
```

After initialization, the file size is 0 bytes.

```
[4] (pry) main: 0> foo.write('a')
=> 1
[5] (pry) main: 0> File.size(foo.path)
=> 0
```

After writing one character to `foo`, the data has been buffered and not flushed to disk as I'd expect.

```
[6] (pry) main: 0> foo.size
=> 1
[7] (pry) main: 0> File.size(foo.path)
=> 1
```

`foo.size` flushes the buffer then returns the size of the file, which matches what `File.size` says it is.

When dealing with temporary files created by Tempfile, we don't care or want to know what their size is. They're temporary and will disappear (eventually) and are treated like buffers. If you need a file that is more permanent, then create and write to a normal file.